# Uploading file via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am trying to upload file using ajax.

```
form enctype="myltipart/form-data" id="pastTest-form" method="POST" action="upload.php">
            <div class="feedback-form-inputs col-5">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <select id="type" required>
                        <option value="quiz">Quiz</option>
                        <option value="midterm">Midterm</option>
                        <option value="final">Final</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" id="professor"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" id="name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="file" accept="" required />
                </div>
            </div><!-- END feedback-form-inputs -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit() />
                <div id="upload-status"> </div>
            </form>
```

my function for opening ajax are in the external file.

```
function addPastTest1(cid){
    // form variables
    var type = _("type").value;
    var professor = _("professor").value;
    var name = _("name").value;

    var fileSelect = _('uploaded_file');
    var status = _('upload-status');
    event.preventDefault();
    // Update status text.
    status.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
    // Get the selected files from the input.
    var file = fileSelect.files[0];

    var FileName = file.name;
    var FileSize = file.size;
    var allowed = ["msword", "pdf","pages"];
    var found = false;
    // check if the extension of the file match the allowed ones
    allowed.forEach(function(extension) {
        if (file.type.match('application/'+extension)) {
          found = true;
        }
    })
    if (FileSize >10204){
        status.innerHtml = 'File must be less than 1mb in size';
    }
    if (found==true){
        // Create a new FormData object.
        var formData = new FormData();
        // Add the file to the request.
        formData.append('file', file, FileName);
        // Set up the request.
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "ajaxResponse.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (ajaxReturn(ajax)==true){
                if (ajax.responseText=='failed'){
                status.innerHtml = "failed to upload file";
                }
                else {
                    status.innerHtml = 'uploaded';
                    alert(ajax.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send(formData);            //ajax.send("f="+formData+"&t="+type+"&p="+professor+"&n="+name+"&cid="+cid+"&fn="+FileName);
    }
}
```

so i am sending formData to the php. but at this point i can not take the file from form data and upload it to the server.
here is my php

```
// Ajax calls this code to add a past test
if (isset($_FILES['file']){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
            $path = 'files/'.$type.'/'.$fileName;
            $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file, $path);

        if ($moveResult != true) {
            echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
            //unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
            exit();
        }


    $path = 'files/'.$type.'/'.$fileName;
    $sql = "INSERT into past_papers VALUES ('$name', '$type', '$cid', '$professor','$path')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx)>0){
        echo "success";
        exit();
        }   
    else {
        echo "failed sql";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Also i want to grab inputs with the file and process them together. Upload file, and insert inputs into database.

Comment: You should use the search function, tons of post are related to this for example

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously?rq=1

Also

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+ajax+upload

Comment: Your upload handling is totally invalid. you need to check `$_FILES['file']['error']` **FIRST**, to see if an upload was acctually performed AND succeeded. You're simply assuming nothing could ever go wrong, which is exactly the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one I can find. :)

> jQuery code

```
$("#form-id").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "file-to-call.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //handle success
        }
   });
}));
```

> HTML code

```
<form name='form1' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='form-id'>
    <input type='submit' id='input' value='Upload' />
</form>
```